# Child items overlay-ed by parent layout in Android Studio Design

Tags: android, android-studio

Can anybody how to remove this parent NavDrawer overlay showing whilst designing layout? (Screen 1).

The overlay is removed when running in actual device (Screen 2).

Because of this I can't design child elements right there in the studio.

Any help would be great!

[image: Screen 1 in Android Design]

[image: Screen 2 in Actual Device]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Always Visible."
        />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see that gray block with the tag name in it, that means that Android Studio can't resolve the class from the tag in your layout, so it doesn't know what to preview. Often this will happen if you have a typo in your layout file, but then you wouldn't see it working when you actually run the app.

For me, I can make this happen quite easily by using the old support library versions of widgets, since I have AndroidX enabled in my project. For example, just pasting your code in to my IDE gives me the same gray box, but changing your tags to use AndroidX fixes it (`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` -> `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout`).

Chances are good that your Android Studio just needs a kick in the pants.

I suggest doing a Gradle Sync (`File` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`) and, if that doesn't work, an Invalidate + Restart (`File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`).